# How can I get the last row from a table mysqli?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table and am trying to get the most recent row using this code:

```
include "db_conx.php";

$sql="SELECT column FROM table ORDER BY DESC LIMIT 1";

if ($result=mysqli_query($db_conx,$sql))
  {
  while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
  {
  printf($row[0]);
  }
  mysqli_free_result($result);
}
```

It returns a blank result though.

Comment: is there any primary ID inside the table ot timestamp?

Comment: `$sql="SELECT column FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";` where `id` must be `primary key`

Comment: No. There was but I removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ORDER BY DESC LIMIT 1
```

ORDER BY ***what*** DESC?  You have to provide a column name where which you want to order by. Could be an Auto increment column, primary key or even the timestamp etc

As it currently stands your query has invalid syntax and will not return anything other than an error.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't see that

Answer (score 1):

For the **ORDER BY** you should give a column name of the table.
Ex  : `SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME ORDER BY table_id DESC LIMIT 1`

In your query you missed the column name to order by.

Answer (score 0):

you missed column name after order by clause. hope it helps !